# OpenGL glUniform1f not updating vertex shader

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

All the tutorials seem to indicate that I am doing things correctly, the vertex shader works, however it fails to recognize any input changes from the main program through the use of the `glUniform1f` function.  I check `glGetError` after each line, there are no errors.  I check `glGetShaderiv` and `glGetShaderInfoLog`, there are no issues.  I am testing with OpenGL version 2.1 (unknown profile, but assuming the core profile) as reported by SDL.

```
#if defined(__WINDOWS__) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__TOS_WIN__)\
    || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    /* Compiling for Windows */
    #ifndef __WINDOWS__
        #define __WINDOWS__
    #endif
    #include <windows.h>
#endif/* Predefined Windows macros */

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>

//return type not verified
void glGenBuffers();
void glBindBuffer();
void glBufferData();
unsigned int glCreateShader();
void glShaderSource();
void glCompileShader();
void glGetShaderiv();
void glGetShaderInfoLog();
unsigned int glCreateProgram();
void glAttachShader();
void glLinkProgram();
void glGetProgramiv();
void glGetProgramInfoLog();
void glVertexAttribPointer();
void glEnableVertexAttribArray();
void glUseProgram();
void glDeleteShader();
void glGenVertexArrays();
void glBindVertexArray();
GLint glGetUniformLocation();
void glUniform1f();
void glDeleteProgram();
void glDeleteBuffers();

int fixSDLconsole() {
    FILE *console = freopen("stdout.txt", "a",stdout);
    if (console == NULL) {return errno;}
    console = freopen("stdout.txt", "a",stderr);
    if (console == NULL) {return errno;}
    return 0;
}
void printGLVersionNumber() {
    int majorVersion;
    int minorVersion;
    int profile;
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, &majorVersion);
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, &minorVersion);
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &profile);
    fprintf(stderr,"GL version %d.%d ",majorVersion,minorVersion);
    switch (profile) {
        case SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE: fprintf(stderr,"core (%d)\n",profile);break;
        case SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY: fprintf(stderr,"compatibility (%d)\n",profile);break;
        case SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES: fprintf(stderr,"E.S. (%d)\n",profile);break;
        default: fprintf(stderr, "unknown profile: %d\n",profile);break;
    }
    return;
}
#define checkGlError(label) {int error = glGetError();if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"error=%d", error);goto label;}}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_GLContext context = NULL;
    GLuint verticesGlIds[] = {0,0};
    GLuint vertexShaderGlId = 0;
    GLuint shaderProgramGlId = 0;
    if (fixSDLconsole()) {
        return errno;
    }
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        error_at_line(1,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"Unable to initialize SDL: %s",SDL_GetError());
        goto error;
    }
    printGLVersionNumber();

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window Title",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640,640,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"Could not create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto error;
    }
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (context == NULL) {
        error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"Could not create OpenGL context: %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto error;
    }

    glViewport(0,0,640,640);checkGlError(error);
    glClearColor(.9f,.9f,.9f,1.f);checkGlError(error);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);checkGlError(error);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);checkGlError(error);

    float vertices[] = {
        -.5f,0.f,0.f,
        0.f,.5f,0.f,
        0.f,-.5f,0.f,
        0.f,.5f,0.f,
        .5f,.5f,0.f,
        0.f,0.f,0.f
    };
    float colors[] = {
        1.f,0.f,0.f,//red
        .5f,0.f,0.f,//red
        0.f,1.f,0.f,//green
        0.f,.5f,0.f,//green
        0.f,0.f,1.f,//blue
        0.f,0.f,.5f//blue
    };
    glGenBuffers(2, &verticesGlIds);checkGlError(error);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesGlIds[0]);checkGlError(error);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);checkGlError(error);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesGlIds[1]);checkGlError(error);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(colors),colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);checkGlError(error);

    char *vertexShader =
        "#version 120\n"\
        "attribute vec3 aPos;\n"\
        "uniform float i;\n"\
        "void main() {\n"\
        "gl_FrontColor=gl_Color;\n"\
        "gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x+i/2,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0);\n"\
        "}\n";
    vertexShaderGlId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);checkGlError(error);
    if (vertexShaderGlId == 0) {error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"vertex shader could not be created");goto error;}
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderGlId, 1, &vertexShader, NULL);checkGlError(error);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderGlId);checkGlError(error);
    {
        GLint success;
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderGlId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);checkGlError(error);
        if (success == GL_FALSE) {
            char infoLog[512];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderGlId, 512, NULL, infoLog);checkGlError(error);
            error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"Vertex Shader problem: %s", infoLog);
            goto error;
        }
    }

    shaderProgramGlId = glCreateProgram();checkGlError(error);
    if (shaderProgramGlId == 0) {error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"shader program could not be created");goto error;}
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramGlId, vertexShaderGlId);checkGlError(error);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgramGlId);checkGlError(error);
    {
        int success;
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramGlId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);checkGlError(error);
        if (!success) {
            char infoLog[512];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramGlId, 512, NULL, infoLog);checkGlError(error);
            error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"Shader program problem: %s", infoLog);
        }
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderGlId);checkGlError(error);

    GLint iLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramGlId, "i");checkGlError(error);
    if (iLocation == -1) {error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"uniform i not found in shader");goto error;}
    error_at_line(0,0,__FILE__,__LINE__,"iLocation: %d", iLocation);

    for (int frame = 0; frame < 100; ++frame) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);checkGlError(error);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgramGlId);checkGlError(error);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesGlIds[0]);    checkGlError(error);
        glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);    checkGlError(error);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesGlIds[1]);    checkGlError(error);
        glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0); checkGlError(error);
        glUniform1f(iLocation, (float) (frame%2));  checkGlError(error);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(float)/3); checkGlError(error);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   checkGlError(error);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        SDL_Delay(100);
    }
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgramGlId);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderGlId);
    glDeleteBuffers(sizeof(verticesGlIds)/sizeof(GLuint), verticesGlIds);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    error:
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgramGlId);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderGlId);
    glDeleteBuffers(sizeof(verticesGlIds)/sizeof(GLuint), verticesGlIds);
    if (context != NULL) SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    if (window != NULL) SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
#if defined(__WINDOWS__)
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    char *argv[1] = {(char *) 0};
    return main(0, argv);
}
#endif
```

note that I am not familiar with OpenGL's extension function loading issues and routines such as SDL's `SDL_GL_LoadLibrary` and `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` I just manually define the method signatures at the top of the file and import GL through the linker.  I don't expect this to be an issue but it is the only issue, I am aware of, that I haven't looked into, that may be causing my problems.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure it varies with time?

Comment: I dont see any draw call. Did you omit it or it is simply not there?

Comment: Your code snippet is missing something important: The actual drawing commands. Without seeing where drawing happens in relation to the rest of the OpenGL operations it's nigh impossible to tell, what the problem is.

Comment: @datenwolf edited to include missing draw command

Comment: @immibis yes, even passing in different constant values to `glUniform1f` results in no change to the displayed triangles, it is as if the vertex shader thinks the uniform `i` is always 0, but when I change the vertex shader directly by varying `-1` to `-0.5` I can see the difference so I know the shader *is* working.... I will edit the question with a compilable version within 12 hours.

Comment: " I just manually define the method signatures at the top of the file and import GL through the linker." This part is definitively missing in your question.

Comment: Oh, good spotting derhass. Yes, that "only issue you're aware of" could be the reason it doesn't work. Go fix it and see if it works then.

Comment: makes no sense, but using SDL to import the functions at runtime fixes the issue even though the functions imported from the dll at load time should be the same.

Comment: I must protest the reason for closing this question as it is obviously wrong.  The question includes the desired behavior, the observed problem and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it, it's right there in front of you, plain as day... the gl dll's provided on my system obviously have fake symbol tables that provide decoy functions that can only handle basic features.  If this means that a separate question must exist for each and every function available, that isn't my fault, it is the fault of either the maintainer of my O.S. software repo or the GPU manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you declare the function like this:

> ```
> void glUniform1f();
> ```

By omitting any parameters, the compiler will assume that all arguments are of type `int`. For most other GL functions, this works by chance, because those arguments are just integer types in most cases anyway, but for `glUniform1f`, it will mean that the function argument is *converted* to integer, but the resulting bit-pattern is implicitely *re-interpreted* as `GLfloat` by the function since the actual prototype for `glUniform1f` is something like this

```
void glUniform1f(int location, GLfloat value);
```

> note that I am not familiar with OpenGL's extension function loading issues and routines such as SDL's `SDL_GL_LoadLibrary` and `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` I just manually define the method signatures at the top of the file and import GL through the linker.

You shouldn't do this. The GL functions you try to access might not even be *exported* by the library at all. If you do not want to manually deal with loading every function pointer, you can use one of the existing [OpenGL loaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: Opengl headers only being distributed as version *1.0*, and anything else requiring absurd unstandardized extension loading libraries, is why I have come to regard Khronos group as my kind of people: murderous misanthropes. (f.y.i. for idiots: this is a half-joke)

Answer (score 0):

`gl_Position` expects *Clip-space* coordinates, which are a hiper-cube of size [2w,2w,2w,w].

For `vec4(x, y, z, w)` if any of the [x,y,z] is outside of `[-w,w]` range, then the vertex is clipped.

The coordinates will be automatically converted by the GPU to *NDC-space* `x/w, y/w, z/w, 1` (aka "perspective division") before the fragment shader.

Your GLSL code `gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x+i/2,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0);` uses the uniform `i`.

You update it by `glUniform1f(iLocation, (float) (frame%2));`

First issue is `frame%2`. Only `0` or `1` is passed to the GPU. With your current vertices data, only two pairs of triangles should be drawn.

Second issue is that `frame` is a value `0 <= frame < 100`. So, if you pass `frame` instead of `frame%2`, then for most values `aPos.x + i/2` will fall outside the Clip space and you will see only the first two triangle-pairs, or parts of them.

Comment: "Clip-space coordinates, which are a hyper-cube of size [2w,2w,2w,w]". Not exactly. The clip condition is `-w <= x,y,z <= w`, so the `w` dimension itself is unbounded. I'd also not the case that the _clip coordinates_ are a hyper-cube - the space is infinite. The _viewing volume_ in clip space is restricted by the above condition, but the resulting 4D volume isn't a hypercube, it is still an infinite volume due to the unbounded `w`  - the acutal bounded hypercube comes from the fact that with a projection matrix, `w` is just  a linear function of `z`, but that is no property of the clip space.